# Is there any .NET profiler that connects multiple process/exe

Tags: profiler, asp.net-profiles

I am using the dottrace for .NET application profiling by connecting remote to remote server.Now i want to connect to multiple process which is the part of the one application deployed as microservice.

So is there any profiling tool that allows to connect to multiple process and analyse the application behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to multiple processes is not a recommended way of using profilers as profiling of one process can affect the performance of another process, so all profiling results can be wrong in this case.

But if you want, you can use dotTrace console profiler to profile multiple processes at once (one console profiler run in a separate console for each profiled process); note that in this case, you'll get a separate snapshot for each process, so analyzing of these snapshots will not be very convenient.